# Django ALL in query (as opposed to OR / plain IN clause)

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

Say I have 2 models joined via many-to-many:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
   sports = models.ManyToManyField('Sport')

class Sport(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
   people = models.ManyToManyField('Person')
```

I'd like to perform an AND query to filter Person by those who play ALL sports given a list of sport ids. So something like:

```
Person.objects.filter(sports__id__all=[1,2,3])
```

Or, said differently, exclude anyone that doesn't play ALL the sports.

Comment: Note that you should not define *two* such `ManyToMany` relations, otherwise you make the relation *directed*. Django automatically adds a reverse relation. You can for example specify `related_name='people'` for the `sports` relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Filtering (retaining `People` that play *all* given `Sport`s)

The solution is not trivial. If you however can calculate the *length* of the list, then it can be done by calculating the number of *overlap* between the list of sports, and the `sports` a `Person` plays:

```
from django.db.models import Count

sports_list = [1, 2, 3]

Person.objects.filter(
    sports__in=sports_list
).annotate(
    overlap=Count('sports')
).filter(overlap=len(sports_list))
```

So in case the number of sports of a `Person` that are in the `sports_list` is the number of elements in the `sports_list`, then we know that person plays *all* those sports.

### non-unique `Sport`s in the `sport_list`

Note that `sport_lists` should contain *unique* `Sport` objects (or id's). You can however build a *set* of `sports`, for example:

```
# in case a sport can occur *multiple times in the list

from django.db.models import Count

sports_set = set([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3])

Person.objects.filter(
    sports__in=sports_set
).annotate(
    overlap=Count('sports')
).filter(overlap=len(sports__set))
```

### SQL query

Behind the curtains, we will construct a query like:

```
SELECT `person`.*
FROM `person`
INNER JOIN `person_sport` ON `person`.`id` = `person_sport`.`person_id`
WHERE `person_sport`.`sport_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY `person`.`id`
HAVING COUNT(`person_sport`.`sport_id`) = 3
```

## Excluding (retaining `People` that do *not* play *all* given `Sport`s)

A related problem might be to *exclude* those persons: persons that play all the specified sports. We can do this as well, but then there can occur a problem: people that play no sport at all, will be excluded as well, since the first `.filter(..)` will remove these people. We can however slightly change the code, such that these are included as well:

```
# opposite problem: excluding those people

from django.db.models import Q, Count

sports_set = set([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3])

Person.objects.filter(
    Q(sports__in=sports_set) | Q(sports__isnull=True)
).annotate(
    overlap=Count('sports')
).exclude(overlap=len(sports__set))
```

Comment: This works wonderfully. Thank you! I was just about to drop down and write SQL.